# Are the lightsaber combat forms still canon?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

With reference to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22517/when-were-lightsaber-forms-introduced-to-star-wars). I am referring to the lightsaber combat forms we know of (Form I-VII, as well as other named ones). The various forms are detailed in Star Wars Insider, but I am not sure what is still canon from there, if any.

Comment: Related: Not dupe; [When were lightsaber forms introduced to Star Wars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22517/when-were-lightsaber-forms-introduced-to-star-wars?lq=1)

Comment: @Richard that's what I linked in my question

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty much comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, they're fully (Disney) canon.

The forms are listed in full in the new DK factbook ["Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) and as such are fully part of the new Disney-authorised universe.

There are also references to Form III (*'Soresu'*) in [Kanan: The Last Padawan](http://marvel.com/comics/series/19486/kanan_2015_-_present) and Star Wars: Rebels, references to Form V (*'Shien'*) in Star Wars: Rebels, Star Wars: The Clone Wars and "[Star Wars in 100 Scenes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_in_100_Scenes)" and references to [Form VII](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII/Canon) (*'Juyo'/'Vaapad'*) in the novelisations for both 'Attack of the Clones' and 'Revenge of the Sith'.

Comment: What about the definitions/specifications of each form, have the entire form as we know it (from Wookiepedia, for example) been recycled or is it only the name that is recycled? Any idea about other lightsaber styles besides Form I-VII, such as those developed by the Sith?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - They're described in quite a lot of detail, including the name and an overview of the style. The descriptions quite heavily mirror those found in the "Jedi Manual".